# How can I reduce a video's size by lowering the quality as minimally as possible to archive purpose?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using `convert.sh` in Linux server as below,
By using this shell, the original MP4 file has been changed to small size avi file(100% → 4~5%) compare to the original one.
By the way its' resolution is not good so that we can see macro block on screen.
How can we adjust this video resolution as we want?
Could you please share the solution?

```
 #!/bin/bashmp4file=$(echo *.MP4)
 for file in $mp4file;
 do {
     Outfile=$(echo $file | sed "s/MP4/.avi/g")
     ffmpeg -i $file -c:a copy -s 1280×720 $Outfile   
}
done;
```

Comment: I recommend using a different format than `.avi`, unless this is a hard requirement. You can adjust the bitrate with `-b:v` and the quality of the encoding with `-q`, see `man ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

Use an encoder more efficient than plain mpeg4 such as h264 or even h265. And preferably a more recent container such as mp4. Here is an example using h265:

```
Outfile=$(echo $file | sed "s/MP4/.mp4/g")
ffmpeg -i $file -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -c:a copy $Outfile
```

This example maintains the original video's resolution (in your example, the resolution was set explicitly). Tune the Constant Rate Factor parameter to your liking (smaller numbers for more quality). See the [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for more options and examples.